# Логгирование в aspnet.core 2.2

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Всем привет. Есть небольшая проблема с логированием комплекса на aspnet.core
При деплое комплекс разворачивается под centOS. В appSettings.Production.json указан путь до папки куда класть логи и они туда кладутся, однако дополнительно эти же логи идут в /var/logs/messages. В комплексе несколько сервисов и все они складывают логи туда же, поэтому раздел var забивается достаточно быстро. В документации написано, что при старте приложения, если использован `CreateDefaultBuilder` то добавляются все провайдеры логирования. Попытался решить проблему сбрасыванием провайдеров:

```
`#if !DEBUG
                .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
                {
                    logging.ClearProviders();
                })
#endif`
```

Не помогло. Как писались так и пишутся. 
Подскажите пожалуйста в чем косяк?
Заранее спасибо!

UPD: Прикладываю кусок appsettings.Development.json -

```
"Logging": {
"PathFormat": "..\\Logs\\jana-ui.log",
"LogLevel": {
  "Default": "Debug"
}
```

},

Comment: Логи можно  и нужно отключать в конфигах а не в коде:
https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: @SultanovShamil приложил кусок appsettings.Development.json. В том документы, что Вы скинули приведен пример для поставщика Console. Если поставщики не указаны, по дефолту будут использоваться поставщики DefaultBuilder'а?